# cakephp 3.x updating user data

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have written a basic login script and now need to update the data stored in the auth component and then save it to the database, this is what i have so far;

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {                 
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            $this->Auth->user()->last_activity = date("Y-m-d");
            $this->Users->save($this->Auth->user());
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Email or password is incorrect, please try again.'));
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different variations but can't get any to work. Any ideas?

Comment: That code for sure will trigger an error, as the return value of `AuthComponent::user()` is not an object, but an array. Whenever receiving errors, please include them in your question, including the full stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!

Answer (score 1):

Updating data in cakephp3 is slightly different than cakephp2, Try something like this:

```
public function login()
{
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $user = $this->Auth->identify();
    if ($user) {                 
        $this->Auth->setUser($user);
         $userData = $this->Users->get($user['id']);
         $userData->last_activity = date("Y-m-d");
         if($this->Users->save($userData)){
            $user['last_activity'] = $userData->last_activity; // to update auth component
         }
         // echo $this->Auth->user('last_activity');
         return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('Email or password is incorrect, please try again.'));
 }
}
```

Another way of updating record in cakephp3 is:

```
$query = $this->Users->query();
 $query->update()
->set(['last_activity ' => date('Y-m-d')])
->where(['id' => $user['id']])
->execute();
```

But I don't recommend this one as callbacks are not fired.

Comment: This works somewhat... It updates the db but the auth component is not updated. Therefore after this is completed the auth component has the old date and the db has the new date. Also, it seems that this way is using more memory through another db query through the 'get'. is there not a way to update the data in the auth component and then save that into the db?

Comment: If you need to update both db and auth component try the updated answer..But this is the best way to update records in cakephp3 as mentioned in documentation.

Comment: thanks but the updated answer doesn't change the value stored in the auth component - ie if i do 'echo $this->Auth->user('last_activity');' i get the old value not the new one.

Comment: Where did you do that echo ? see one more time the answer..that should give updated value.

Comment: I have tested this well..still not working for you ?

Answer (score 1):

In Cake3, you can take advantage of the `afterIdentify` event.

In `AppController::initialize`, add a listener for the event:

```
\Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on('Auth.afterIdentify', [$this, 'afterIdentify']);
```

Add `AppController::afterIdentify` function to handle the event:

```
public function afterIdentify(CakeEvent $cakeEvent, $data, $auth) {
    $users_table = TableRegistry::get('Users');

    $user = $users_table->get($data['id']);
    $user->last_activity = new Cake\I18n\FrozenTime();

    // If you ever need to do password rehashing, here's where it goes
    if ($this->Auth->authenticationProvider()->needsPasswordRehash()) {
        $user->password = $this->request->data('password');
    }

    $users_table->save($user);
}
```

Now, the data returned by the `Auth->user()` call should always be up-to-date without any extra effort on your part.

Comment: Thanks, I like this option. I still, however, have the issue that the data in `Auth->user()` is the old data and not the updated `last_activity` data

Comment: Exactly where in your code are you accessing this and getting old information?

Comment: i do `var_dump($this->Auth->user());` in the `User::Account` after the `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());`

Comment: Okay, but that's not a real-world use, right? You're about to redirect, and when the new URL is loaded, it will correctly have the updated information there. Do you have an actual use case where the in-memory data needs to be updated at this point, or is it just a testing thing?

Comment: At the moment the url redirects to the `user.account` method which has the `var_dump`. This is after the url has redirected but the date in the `last_activity` is the old date, not the new one as saved in the db.

Comment: Well, I don't know then. Sorry! I have similar code which, as far as I can tell, does pretty much what you say yours does, but works fine. (Mine redirects somewhere else, but I put a dump of the last login date in there, and it had the updated info.) If you do a manual (F5) refresh of the `user.account` page after this, does the right value show up then?

Comment: No luck with the manual refresh! I'll have to struggle on and find out what's going on

Comment: is the afteridentify event in the API documentation? I can't find it

Comment: There's a brief mention of the `Auth.afterIdentify` event in [the Authentication section of the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects); I expect it's not in the API documentation because it's an event, not an API. If the old value is still showing up for you after a manual refresh, then are you absolutely sure that the database is being updated? If it is, but you're still somehow getting old data from $this->Auth->user, then there must be something else going on, like caching or session data.